# Big O - Code Complexity

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

I am working with Big O and I got this exercise I am working on.

[image: The Exercise]

I know the first line is running in constant time. But I am confused on how to measure the while-loop.

Comment: its clearly quadratic

Comment: How can you see that? Can you please explain?

Comment: Could you write the exercise in your post?

Comment: Yes, it is done now

Comment: Insert print statements that output the values of *i* and *j* in the current iteration.  Run the code and see what is printed put.

Answer (score 1):

The outer loop runs $n$ times.

The inner runs $n-i-1$ times,
and since $i \le n$,
it runs at most $n$ times.

Therefore,
the total is at most
$n\cdot n = n^2$.

Actually,
it is $n^2/2+O(n)$,
but $O(n^2)$
is enough.

Comment: I upvoted your one since you got it first

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't get where the n-i-1 comes from.

Comment: j starts at n and stops when j=i. Difference is n-i-1.

Answer (score 0):

To think of it simply, each time that the outer loop runs, the other loop runs a maximum of n times. Since the outer loop runs n times, we will have n^2 runs, and so the complexity is quadratic.